# Detecting the current tab language using Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, language-detection

Is there a way to use chrome API to detect the language of the current content in the current tab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Chrome Tabs API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-detectLanguage) to select the current tab, then get the language.

Sample usage:

```
//Get language of current tab
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.detectLanguage(tab.id, function(language) {
    console.log(language);
  });
});
```

Comment: The tabId parameter of detectLanguage is optional (undefined can be passed in), so there's no need to use getSelected.

Comment: where does this code go?, it prints the language in the console then?

Comment: @Max The code goes anywhere you can use the `chrome.tabs`, such as a background page. This sample prints in the console.

Answer (score 2):

Yes: `chrome.tabs.detectLanguage`. See http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-detectLanguage.

Comment: where does this code go?, it prints the language in the console then?