# Detecting the language of a frame or a string using Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, frame

I am writing a Google Chrome Extension.  Now I need to detect the language of a frame in a tab.  I read the post  [Detecting the current tab language using Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7654983/797988) but the answers involve  examining the whole tab, apparently.  Here I am in a chat and I have to examine a response in a table in a frame to see if the respondent has changed languages so that I can respond appropriately.

So what I have is either a frame or a string from the table.

Any suggestions?  I am writing in javascript and I am not familiar with jquery.

Comment: my sense of it is that one could use something from here: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/i18n.html

Answer (score 0):

Not directly in the Chrome Extensions API's, but you can create a content_script that attaches a `element.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function() { something })` listener to the area you want to examine and then fire off a request to the [translate api](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html#language_detect) to detect the language.

Comment: Unfortunately this api has been discontinued and replaced with a paid service.